# Getting database response from DTSX SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

Fairly new to DTSX/SSIS packages, currently I have a ton of data that I perform a lookup, whereas to perform lookup and update or insert depending on the lookup

[image]

Currently I am getting an error on either one of the update or insert, is there a way to get the response of the database from the dtsx what the actual database response is? i.e is it truncation issue or primary key constraint. I want to be able to send to email or at least write in the log files what the issue is.

Comment: If this is happening in Visual Studio, after you get the error try clicking on the "Progress" tab at the top of the screen, or the Output window at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, There two ways to log events in SSIS, by using "Logging" or "Event Handlers". Working with Logging option is fairly easy.

1. Go to "Control Flow" tab
2. Right click anywhere on the package and choose Logging
3. In "Provider and Logs" tab you choose how and where logs to save(text file, SQL server ....)
4. In "Details" tab you choose what kind of evens to log. In your case just just choose "OnError

"